# Get index of element from array on click Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a gallery and in that gallery, there would be images wrapped in divs. In jQuery, I could call these divs like:

```
var card = $('.card');
```

This card variable will now contain all the elements with the 'card' class. Now, what I want to happen is whenever I click on a 'card', it would grab that very instance of card (I'm thinking by getting its index onclick) and do something with it as object-oriented as possible (though I never had much experience with it)

Comment: Please click `<>` and create a [mcve]

Comment: @mplungjan im sorry it wasn't very formal. i will read this now

Comment: More important is to give us the HTML and expected output :) PS: Not my downvtote - people here will vote down without considering the newness of the visitor - the downvote is due to lack of code

Comment: thanks for the advice. Its my fault, i didnt give enough info

Comment: `$('.card').on("click",function() { $(this).something()  });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple `this` object:

https://codepen.io/bra1N/pen/ERXPJw

```js
$('.card').on("click",function() { 
    $(this).css('background', 'red'); 
});
```

```css
.card {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">A</div>
<div class="card">B</div>
<div class="card">C</div>
```

Comment: You dont need `each` event.

Comment: `$('.card').on("click",function() {
    $(this).css('background', 'red'); 
});` is more elegant

Comment: I agree with Code_Ninja and mplungjan
Each is not needed here, I just updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do:

Dummy HTML:

```
<div class="card">A</div>
<div class="card">B</div>
<div class="card">C</div>
```

jQuery needed:

```
$('.card').click(function() {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Here is the link to the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maozw9y5/5/) supporting this answer.

```js
$('.card').click(function() {
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">A</div>
<div class="card">B</div>
<div class="card">C</div>
```

Comment: Please click the `<>` and provide the example HERE instead of externally

Comment: Sorry I didnt knew how to do that. So I always give an external link. Thanks btw @mplungjan